# i want my phone to use the sd card i put instead of the phone memory

Tags: settings

Im using a Samsung galaxy s3 mini and my problem is that my phone uses the memory when I have got a sd card which still has got space

Comment: There are plenty of questions and answers on this site already about internal vs external storage and how to utilize an SD card for apps and other data. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/2315/revisions) shows some things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

To fully locate  Apps such as Live wallpaper, etc in SD resulting in more free space on your Internal Memory.

1. Root your phone.
2. Get Link2SD from Play Store (it would be better if you get Link2SD Plus) because Ordinary Link2SD lacks "link Private Data" which  it links Data files of app and gives you more space on your internal memory.
3. Create a 2nd partition in your high class SD Card set it as (Primary EXT-3 or EXT4; EXT4 is the fastest one ) 2nd can be 1G.B or even 2G.B (The smaller the size the faster apps will be opened) using Minitool Partition 8 or 7 (watch a TUT. For that)

4.Insert your SD card to your phone > open Link2SD > a box will pop up asking you about the format of your 2nd partition EXT3 Or 4 and other formats) > Reboot Your phone after choosing format if the same box pops up again after rebooting that means Your 2nd is not recognized yet or it's not identified by the system Try to change its format between EXT2 or EXT3 or EXT4 to check tap on "storage info" and see. 
5. Tap on the app you want to link to SD Card > tap on "create Link" button Check the available options in there "Link apk /app if the app was installed to internal memory, Link Davlik Cache, Link Libraries, Link private data (available only on Link2SD plus).

6. Link or remove bloatware (they're the apps pre-installed on your phone since you bought it). BE CAREFUL DON'T LINK SYSTEM APPS!!
7. From settings check "Auto Clear cache" to free up more space you can exclude some apps if you want too. 
   For apps that they store their files in Internal memory as (Google Translate Offline packages) I found interesting forum on XDA-Developers explaining how to move these files to SD.